# I cannot see my website on Firebase Hosting

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I have a Website created with Vue.js and Firebase. I bought my domain from Godaddy.
My website works fine on this link: https://portfolio-4dd8c.web.app/
but it shows nothing on my domain name: https://ozanbilgic.com/

I added txt host and value that firebase gave me to my godaddy dns. And it tells me "Domain not verified" for 2 days.
What can I do?

Comment: Is you domain name correct and are you sure you added those records correctly? I cannot see any TXT or A records on [DNS checker](https://dnschecker.org/#TXT/ozanbilgic.com)

Comment: _acme-challenge.ozanbilgic.com firebase gave it like this. I added A record when setup mode was Quick Setup. But it didn't work at all and I deleted A Record. then I changed the setup mode to Advanced. there firebase just gave me TXT. and after domain verified it will give me A record.

Comment: When I check with `dig` for `ozanbilgic.com`, I don't see any entries in any DNS server I check. This typically means the DNS zone file was misconfigured, or the change hasn't propagated yet. It's impossible to say for us which one it is, without also seeing how you configured the DNS in Godaddy, but I recommend checking out the top answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-hosting%5D+godaddy.